# Do these make sense?

Tags: grammaire

They sound kind of random and un related but do these two sentences make sense?

"mon petit frère progresse du piano" and "je veux un café"

if not, what are better ways of saying them?

Comment: These questions are unrelated and not described in a way that would make them be useful to someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a wrong article in the first sentence.

> Mon petit frère progresse **au** piano.

The second one is correct but unless it is really a demand, you'd better say:

> Je voudrais un café.